# Want to change different icon on right side setting item

Tags: android, menu

I am working with the navigation drawer and i want to display different icon on different fragment when user click on any item of listview on navigation drawer.

i have did a code in xml of activity which contain navigation drawer.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_setting"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

When i click on any item on list the icon should change. i tried to get reference like,
`@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         mItem = menu.getItem(0);
        return true;
    }`
    But it gives null pointer exception.thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please share the crash log ?

Comment: So you want to change the icon of the ActionBar each time that user chose a List of navigationdrawer?

Answer (score 0):

Try `findItem`:

```
mItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
```

Comment: i replaced this line

`mItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);`
    i m using the mItem object in oncreate() method like,
`@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation__drawer);
//.
//.
//.
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   displayView(0);
 mItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_inbox));
  }
`
    i got error of nullpointer on last line.

Comment: You can use resource id directly `mItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_inbox);`. Is `findItem` returning `null`? Anyway, post your exception trace.